# How to avoid overlapping of text labels in ggrepel

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried every single thing in this tutorial: https://ggrepel.slowkow.com/articles/examples.html
but I wasn't successful repelling the text from each other and keep them aligned without overlapping,
I want something like this:
[image]

But with my trials, I get something like this:

[image]

My code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(dplyr)
library(cowplot)

#Data
fig5cwithoutdesc <- read.csv(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/learnseq/learning/main/fig5cwithoutdesc.txt"),sep = '\t',header = TRUE)
fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs <- trimws(gsub('[[:punct:] ]+',' ',fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs))
fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs.1 <- trimws(gsub('[[:punct:] ]+',' ',fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs.1))
fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs.2 <- trimws(gsub('[[:punct:] ]+',' ',fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs.2))
fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs.3 <- trimws(gsub('[[:punct:] ]+',' ',fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs.3))
fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs.4 <- trimws(gsub('[[:punct:] ]+',' ',fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs.4))
fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs.5 <- trimws(gsub('[[:punct:] ]+',' ',fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs.5))

idza <- c("RPL31", "HSPB1", "MAFB", "ALPL1", "VGF","PCSK1N", "BSG", "CALY", "B2M", "SCG5", "TM4SF4")
idzb <- c("MAFA", "PDX1", "INS", "KCNQ2", "OLFM2", "C1QL1", "PCSKI1N", "SNHG7", "SRP9", "SET", "CALM2", "NDUFA1", "B2M", "PCP4", "SCG3","PFKFB2")
idzg <- c("PPY", "CLU", "GIGYF1", "PTP4A3", "EIF5A", "ALDOA", "CFL1", "NPDC1", "CTSD", "RPLP1", "PCSK1N", "DDX5", "SCG5", "CPG5", "CPE", "LOC643355")
idzd <- c("RBP4", "SST", "PDX1", "C19orf66", "CELF3", "PCSK1N", "TPGS1", "PODXL2", "CDK5R2", "CALY", "LOC728392", "SET", "SRP9", "TSPYL1", "TPD52", "PCP4")
idzacinar <- c("SGK223", "JUND", "RPL7A", "AP1S1", "RBP4", "ENPP2", "ARF4", "TM4SF4", "ATP5O", "PSMD10", "DYNLL1")
idzductal <- c("YBX3", "SERINC2", "PRSS22", "HLA-A", "PPDPF", "EEF2", "SRP9", "SKP1", "B2M", "SDCBP", "CNN3")





    
    
    
library(repr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
options(repr.plot.width=6, repr.plot.height=4)

za <- ggplot(fig5cwithoutdesc,
       aes(a_donor, a_cell, color=(geneIDs %in% idza)))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('gray','royalblue1')) +
  geom_text_repel(data=subset(fig5cwithoutdesc,geneIDs %in% idza),
                  aes(x=a_donor, y=a_cell,label=geneIDs, force=10), 
                  color='black',
                  nudge_y = 0.01,
                  direction = "x",
                  angle = 0,
                  hjust = 0,
                  vjust = 1,
                  segment.size = 0.5) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = 'none', panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())

zb <- ggplot(fig5cwithoutdesc,
       aes(b_donor, b_cell, color=(geneIDs.1 %in% idzb)))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('gray','orange')) +
  geom_text_repel(data=subset(fig5cwithoutdesc,geneIDs.1 %in% idzb),
                  aes(x=b_donor, y=b_cell,label=geneIDs.1, force=10), 
                  color='black',
                  nudge_y = 0.01,
                  direction = "x",
                  angle = 0,
                  hjust = 1,
                  vjust = 1,
                  segment.size = 0.5) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = 'none', panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())


zg <- ggplot(fig5cwithoutdesc,
       aes(g_donor, g_cell, color=(geneIDs.2 %in% idzg)))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('gray','brown2')) +
  geom_text_repel(data=subset(fig5cwithoutdesc,geneIDs.2 %in% idzg),
                  aes(x=g_donor, y=g_cell,label=geneIDs.2, force=10), 
                  color='black',
                  nudge_y = 0.01,
                  direction = "x",
                  angle = 0,
                  hjust = 1,
                  vjust = 1,
                  segment.size = 0.5) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = 'none', panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())


zd <- ggplot(fig5cwithoutdesc,
       aes(d_donor, d_cell, color=(geneIDs.3 %in% idzd)))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('gray','cyan')) +
  geom_text_repel(data=subset(fig5cwithoutdesc,geneIDs.3 %in% idzd),
                  aes(x=d_donor, 
                      y=d_cell,
                      label=geneIDs.3, 
                      force=10), 
                  color='black',
                  segment.size  = 0.2,
                  segment.color = "grey50", 
                  direction     = "y", 
                  hjust         = 1) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = 'none', panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())


zacinar <- ggplot(fig5cwithoutdesc,
       aes(acinar_donor, acinar_cell, color=(geneIDs.4 %in% idzacinar)))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('gray','purple')) +
  geom_text_repel(data=subset(fig5cwithoutdesc,geneIDs.4 %in% idzacinar),
                  aes(x=acinar_donor, y=acinar_cell,label=geneIDs.4, force=10), 
                  color='black',
                  nudge_y = 0.01,
                  direction = "x",
                  angle = 0,
                  hjust = 1,
                  vjust = 1,
                  segment.size = 0.5) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = 'none', panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())


zductal <- ggplot(fig5cwithoutdesc,
       aes(ductal_donor, ductal_cell, color=(geneIDs.5 %in% idzductal)))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('gray','blue1')) +
  geom_text_repel(data=subset(fig5cwithoutdesc,geneIDs.5 %in% idzductal),
                  aes(x=ductal_donor, y=ductal_cell,label=geneIDs.5, force=10), 
                  color='black',
                  nudge_y = 0.01,
                  direction = "x",
                  angle = 0,
                  hjust = 1,
                  vjust = 1,
                  segment.size = 0.5) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = 'none', panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())


library(repr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
options(repr.plot.width=17, repr.plot.height=10)

plot_grid(za, zb, zg, zd, zacinar, zductal, nrow=2, labels= "AUTO")
```

How to achieve the same thing in the first image?

Answer (score 0):

how about the following:

```
fig5cwithoutdesc$labels.a <- fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs
fig5cwithoutdesc$labels.a[fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs %!in% idza] <- ""

fig5cwithoutdesc$labels.b <- fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs.1
fig5cwithoutdesc$labels.b[fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs.1 %!in% idzb] <- ""

# ...
# etc. for other labels


theme1 <- theme_bw()+  theme(legend.position = 'none', panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())

za <- ggplot(fig5cwithoutdesc, aes(x=a_donor, y=a_cell, label=labels.a, color=(geneIDs %in% idza)))+
  geom_point() + scale_color_manual(values = c('gray','royalblue1')) +
  geom_text_repel(color='black') +  theme1

zb <- ggplot(fig5cwithoutdesc, aes(x=b_donor, y=b_cell, label=labels.b, color=(geneIDs.1 %in% idzb)))+
  geom_point() + scale_color_manual(values = c('gray','orange')) +
  geom_text_repel(color='black') +  theme1

# ...
# etc. for other plots
```

[image: a and b]